# Method local inner class vs inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes

The below code produces the output `middle`. Can anyone explain in detail how this is happening?

Is it because the declaration of "inner" version of `class A` comes after the instance of `class A` is created in the `go()` method?

```
class A {
    void m() {
        System.out.println("outer");
    }
}

public class MethodLocalVSInner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MethodLocalVSInner().go();
    }

    void go() {
        new A().m();
        class A {
            void m() {
                System.out.println("inner");
            }
        }
    }

    class A {
        void m() {
            System.out.println("middle");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to rename the *inner* class `A` to `B` and you'll get `outer` output. This should give you a hint.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am going through a hard time choosing one particular answer as many of your answers are correct and to the point.

Comment: You will get a warning in eclipse IDE `The type A is never used locally`, That says local class `A` defined inside method `go` is never used.

Comment: I am curious to know for which requirement you are implementing this ? or its just a tricky question...!!

Comment: new A() will return instance of type that nearest (in same block, same method, same class...). Of course, if they are in same block/method, that class must be declared before new instance statement.
In your case, if you have a package name. You can use "new packagename.A().m()" for "outer"

Comment: I chose the answer of @RohitJain because of the exact references he gave in addition to his explanation.

Comment: @KisHanSarsecHaGajjar Was solving some exercises from a book and I landed into this problem.

Comment: @KisHanSarsecHaGajjar But you can get similar situations when designing some GUI applications in java/swing or while making android apps. Attaching event listeners use anonymous inner class significantly.

Comment: Ideally, you will never face this situation if you use meaningful class names and proper design structure !! If you arrive at this situation at any point of time during implementation...stop coding...get one pen and paper...REDESIGN !!!

Comment: @KisHanSarsecHaGajjar This exact situation you may not but I was referring to anonymous inner class :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I guess you expected the local class method to be invoked. That didn't happen, because you're using `new A()` outside the scope of local class. So, it accesses the next closer candidate in scope, that would be the inner class. From [JLS §6.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3):

> The scope of a local class declaration immediately enclosed by a block (§14.2) is the rest of the immediately enclosing block, including its own class declaration.

Thus, `new A()` in the first line of method, will not access the local class appearing after it. If you move the class declaration before that, you'll get the expected output.

Also see [JLS §14.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3), which contains similar example.

Comment: @Radiodef Well, what is missing?

Comment: `If you move the class declaration before that, you'll get the expected output`...by hiding class `MethodLocalVSInner.A` !! PS : Not a downvoter :D

Comment: @KisHanSarsecHaGajjar You mean *shadowing*. ; ) *Shadowing* and *hiding* are different things.

Comment: @KisHanSarsecHaGajjar Isn't it implicit that local class will shadow the inner class?

Comment: @RohitJain I thought that will be a good explicit mention for readers who are less aware about inner class concepts ( or hiding/shadowing concepts ) !!!

Comment: @Radiodef Yup...its [shadowing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html#shadowing) !! My mistake !!

Comment: @RohitJain Can you tell me why declaring the class before `new A().m()` brings it to the scope and it prints `inner`.

Comment: @KisHanSarsecHaGajjar Why do you write so many exclamation marks ?

Comment: @Ramswaroop The answer to your question may simply be that the Java architects chose local classes to behave this way.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually I wanted this to be included in the answer. Because this was what I wanted to know. I thought I may be missing something here but it seems local classes have been designed this way.

Comment: @Ramswaroop I guess the JLS section which I quoted, about scope explains that pretty well.

Answer (score 16):

You are getting the output "middle" because of the order in which you have your code.  Since the method-scoped `class A` occurs **after** your call to `new A()`, you are getting the output "middle".  If you switch around the order as follows, you will get the output "inner":

```
void go() {
    class A {
        void m() {
            System.out.println("inner");
        }
    }
    new A().m();
}
```

**Output:**

`inner`

The order of precedence for instantiating `class A`, from high to low, is:

1. block
2. method
3. class
4. package

Please have a look at the official [Java Language Specification discussing inner classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) for more information.

Comment: That's what the OP also guessed. But why is that? Please back up your answer.

Comment: Then find the JLS reference that proves it - currently it's just speculation.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Can you tell me why declaring the class before new A().m() brings it to the scope and it prints inner?

Comment: As @Radiodef pointed out in his answer, as soon as you define the local class `A` in a block, the scope for that class is the remainder of the block after, but not before, that definition.  As to why the Java architects decided to do it this way, that is another question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually I wanted this to be included in the answer. Because this was what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 7):

The reason `inner` doesn't get printed is ([6.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3)):

> The scope of a local class declaration immediately enclosed by a block is the rest of the immediately enclosing block, including its own class declaration.

(A class declared inside a method is called a local class.)

So `A` can't refer to the local class, because the expression `new A()` happens before its declaration. In other words, local classes have similar scope to local variables.

The reason `middle` gets printed instead of `outer` is that the inner class `A` *shadows* the top-level class `A` ([6.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1)):

> A declaration `d` of a type named `n` shadows the declarations of any other types named `n` that are in scope […] of `d`.

This means that anywhere in the body of `MethodLocalVSInner`, the unqualified `A` must refer to the inner class.

If you are familiar with shadowing of member variables e.g.:

```
class Example {
    int x;
    void setX(int x) {
        //       ┌ 'x' refers to the local method parameter
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

Essentially the same thing is going on with class declarations.

Answer (score 4):

Case 1:

```
void go() {
        new A().m();
        class A {
            void m() {
                System.out.println("inner");
            }
        }
    }
```

In this case if you running your method outside the scope of local class. That  why it will print `middle`

Case 2:

```
void go() {
        class A {
            void m() {
                System.out.println("inner");
            }
        }
        new A().m();
    }
```

In this case it will print `inner` becase class is now in the scope.

Answer (score 2):

in method :

```
 void go() {
    new A().m();
    class A {
        void m() {
            System.out.println("inner");
        }
    }
}
```

when method is started executing, first line will be executed 
`new A().m();`

and because inner class is already in scope so object for that class will be created and `m` method will be called for `inner class` not for `local method class` because its still not in scope. that is why you are getting `middle` as output.

but if you change your method as :

```
 void go() {

    class A {
        void m() {
            System.out.println("inner");
        }
    }
   new A().m();
}
```

Your local method class will now be in scope and will have higher preference so you will get output now `inner`.

Comment: This is not related to class loading. When the method is executed a second time, it will still generate the same output, even though the local class A is already loaded.

Comment: it because of scope preference also. which goes like method then class. @ErwinBolwidt i have change it now.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `go` method using an instance of `MethodLocalVSInner`

Inside the go method
you are creating an instance of `A()`
here since you are not explicitly import the outer `A class` and immediate inner class is after the method calling statement, JVM is picking the `inner class A` which is in the class level of `MethodLocalVSInner` and execute the go method inside that